# CSS height adjustment for some div

Tags: html, css

```css
#ArticlesPane
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
    /*background-color: #4F2412;*/
    /*border: 5px solid yellow;*/
    /*clear: both;*/
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;    
    line-height: 25px;
}

#ArticlesPane > div  /* select direct children */
{
    display: inline-block;    
    height: 100%;   /* This is used to spread background color */
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.ArticlesTitle
{
    background-color: #C9A798;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.ArticlesList
{
    padding: 15px;
}

#pos1.GroupedArticles, #pos2.GroupedArticles
{
    /*width: 34%;*/
    width: 50%;
}

#pos1.GroupedArticles
{
    background-color: #828E8C;
}

#pos2.GroupedArticles
{
    background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

```html
<div id="ArticlesPane">
  <div class="GroupedArticles" id="pos1">    
    <div class="ArticlesTitle">Latest posts 1</div>
    <div class="ArticlesList">
      <a href="">title</a><br />
      <span>Some Text</span>
      <a href="">title</a><br />
      <span>Some Text</span>
      <a href="">title</a><br />
      <span>Some Text</span>
      <a href="">title</a><br />
      <span>Some Text</span>
      ...
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="GroupedArticles" id="pos2">   
    <div class="ArticlesTitle">Latest posts 2</div>
    <div class="ArticlesList">
      <!-- same as above (with any number of items in it) -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to build a two-column layout in which each column contains some articles (title and a summary for each article).
[image] 
The problem is with the height. I'm trying to set a height in a way that it fits all of box content and with zooming in I won't get a scroll bar for the box or the text won't go out of it. Also I want to set a background color spread downwards (to fill the height of ArticlesPane).
With my own code, the text goes out of the box. How can I make the box grow with the text without messing layout.

Comment: i thing this link http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshkhatri13/APJ3e/ helpful to you

Comment: @TMDinesh That's using jquery and this question doesn't have jquery tag. Do you know other css method?

Comment: http://codepen.io/mariemosley/pen/de1e021d39f7ab2a4236bfbd4aad6c1f im not sure its working or not try this

Answer (score 0):

```
 body
 {
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 #pos1.GroupedArticles
 {
   background-color: cornsilk;
   float:left; 
   display:inline-block;
 }

 #pos2.GroupedArticles
 {
   background-color: #828E8C;
   float:left; 
   display:inline-block;
 }
 .ArticlesList
 {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: right;
 }
```

Comment: overflow: hidden will clip the content and is not what I'm looking for.